# almacenar tabla html en base de datos con laravel

Tags: laravel

como puedo almacenar una tabla html por medio de un post a una base de datos usando laravel, si es que alguien tiene algún ejemplo que me pueda servir se los agradecería

```html
    <div class="content">
        <div class="idealsteps-container">
            <nav class="idealsteps-nav"></nav>
            <form action="/formularioMostrar" onsubmit="enviar()" method="post" role="form" novalidate autocomplete="off"
                class="idealforms" id="myForm">
                <div class="idealsteps-wrap">

                    <!-- Step 1 -->

                    <section class="idealsteps-step ">
                        <legend>
                            <h2>Datos Persona Juridica</h2>
                        </legend>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Rut:</label>
                            <input name="rut" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Razón Social:</label>
                            <input name="razon_social" type="email">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Domicilio:</label>
                            <input name="domicilio" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Ciudad:</label>
                            <input name="ciudad" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">País Constitución:</label>
                            <input name="pais_const" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Teléfono:</label>
                            <input id="telefono" name="telefono" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Rut Rep. Legal: </label>
                            <input name="rep_rut" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Nombre Rep. Legal:</label>
                            <input name="rep_nom" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Tipo de Entidad:</label>
                            <select name="tipo_entidad" id="tipo_entidad">
                                <option value="default">&ndash; Seleccione una opción &ndash;</option>
                                <option>Anónima</option>
                                <option>Colectiva</option>
                                <option>En comandita</option>
                                <option>Limitada</option>
                                <option>EIRL</option>
                                <option>Otra</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>

                        <div class="field buttons">
                            <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
                            <button type="button" class="next">Siguiente &raquo;</button>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                    <!-- Step 2 -->

                    <section class="idealsteps-step">
                        <legend>
                            <h2>Identificación Beneficiarios Finales o de Control Efectivo</h2>
                        </legend>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Cédula:</label>
                            <input id="cedulaBF" name="cedulaBF" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Nombres:</label>
                            <input id="nombresBF" name="nombresBF" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Apellidos:</label>
                            <input id="apellidosBF" name="apellidosBF" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Domicilio:</label>
                            <input id="domicilioBF" name="domicilioBF" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Ciudad:</label>
                            <input id="ciudadBF" name="ciudadBF" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">País:</label>
                            <input id="paisBF" name="paisBF" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">% de participación en la PJ declarante:</label>
                            <input id="porcentaje" name="porcentaje" type="text">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field buttons">
                            <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
                            <button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Anterior</button>
                            <button type="button" class="next">Siguiente &raquo;</button>
                            <button id="adicionar" class="btn-tabla" type="button" onclick="guardarDatos()">Agregar
                                Beneficiario</button>
                                <button id="btn-nuevo" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Confirmar()" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                        Agregar
                                </button>
                          
                        </div>

                        <div class="field">
                            <div>
                                <!-- tabla de beneficiarios-->
                                <p>Elementos en la Tabla:
                                    <div id="adicionados"></div>
                                </p>

                            </div>

                            <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">

                                <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                                <th>Cédula</th>
                                                <th>Nombres</th>
                                                <th>Apellidos</th>
                                                <th>Domicilio</th>
                                                <th>Ciudad</th>
                                                <th>País</th>
                                                <th>Porcentaje</th>
                                                <th>Eliminar</th>
                                            </tr>

                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>


                                        </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>



                    </section>

                    <!-- Step 3 -->

                    <section class="idealsteps-step">

                        <legend>
                            <h2>Antecedentes de la persona natural que hace la presente declaración</h2>
                        </legend>

                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Rut:</label>
                            <input name="rutD" type="text" placeholder="000-000-0000">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Nombres:</label>
                            <input name="nombreD" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Apellido Paterno:</label>
                            <input name="apelP" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Apellido Materno:</label>
                            <input name="apelM" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Lugar de Origen:</label>
                            <input name="lugarOrigen" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="main">Relación con la persona juridica tratante:</label>
                            <input name="relacion" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                            <span class="error"></span> </div>

                        <div class="field buttons">
                            <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
                            <button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Anterior</button>
                            <button id="enviar" name="enviar" onclick="almacenarArray()" class="submit">Enviar</button>

                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <span id="invalid"></span>
            </form>





        </div>
    </div>
```

esto es lo que quiero almacenar, es un step y en la parte 2 es donde necesito agregar mas de un beneficiario si bien puedo crear la tabla no se como leer después los datos para almacenarlos en la base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var $ = (s) => document.querySelector(s);

var datos = $("div[class='content']");
//enviamos por post atraves de ajax

//en php seria
/*

$datos = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST["datos"]));

*/
```

```html
 <div class="content">
            <div class="idealsteps-container">
                <nav class="idealsteps-nav"></nav>
                <form action="/formularioMostrar" onsubmit="enviar()" method="post" role="form" novalidate autocomplete="off"
                    class="idealforms" id="myForm">
                    <div class="idealsteps-wrap">

                        <!-- Step 1 -->

                        <section class="idealsteps-step ">
                            <legend>
                                <h2>Datos Persona Juridica</h2>
                            </legend>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Rut:</label>
                                <input name="rut" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Razón Social:</label>
                                <input name="razon_social" type="email">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Domicilio:</label>
                                <input name="domicilio" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Ciudad:</label>
                                <input name="ciudad" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">País Constitución:</label>
                                <input name="pais_const" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Teléfono:</label>
                                <input id="telefono" name="telefono" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Rut Rep. Legal: </label>
                                <input name="rep_rut" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Nombre Rep. Legal:</label>
                                <input name="rep_nom" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Tipo de Entidad:</label>
                                <select name="tipo_entidad" id="tipo_entidad">
                                    <option value="default">&ndash; Seleccione una opción &ndash;</option>
                                    <option>Anónima</option>
                                    <option>Colectiva</option>
                                    <option>En comandita</option>
                                    <option>Limitada</option>
                                    <option>EIRL</option>
                                    <option>Otra</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>

                            <div class="field buttons">
                                <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
                                <button type="button" class="next">Siguiente &raquo;</button>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                        <!-- Step 2 -->

                        <section class="idealsteps-step">
                            <legend>
                                <h2>Identificación Beneficiarios Finales o de Control Efectivo</h2>
                            </legend>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Cédula:</label>
                                <input id="cedulaBF" name="cedulaBF" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Nombres:</label>
                                <input id="nombresBF" name="nombresBF" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Apellidos:</label>
                                <input id="apellidosBF" name="apellidosBF" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Domicilio:</label>
                                <input id="domicilioBF" name="domicilioBF" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Ciudad:</label>
                                <input id="ciudadBF" name="ciudadBF" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">País:</label>
                                <input id="paisBF" name="paisBF" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">% de participación en la PJ declarante:</label>
                                <input id="porcentaje" name="porcentaje" type="text">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field buttons">
                                <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
                                <button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Anterior</button>
                                <button type="button" class="next">Siguiente &raquo;</button>
                                <button id="adicionar" class="btn-tabla" type="button" onclick="guardarDatos()">Agregar
                                    Beneficiario</button>
                                    <button id="btn-nuevo" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Confirmar()" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                            Agregar
                                    </button>
                              
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <div>
                                    <!-- tabla de beneficiarios-->
                                    <p>Elementos en la Tabla:
                                        <div id="adicionados"></div>
                                    </p>

                                </div>

                                <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">

                                    <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                    <th>Cédula</th>
                                                    <th>Nombres</th>
                                                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                                                    <th>Domicilio</th>
                                                    <th>Ciudad</th>
                                                    <th>País</th>
                                                    <th>Porcentaje</th>
                                                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                                                </tr>

                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>


                                            </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>



                        </section>

                        <!-- Step 3 -->

                        <section class="idealsteps-step">

                            <legend>
                                <h2>Antecedentes de la persona natural que hace la presente declaración</h2>
                            </legend>

                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Rut:</label>
                                <input name="rutD" type="text" placeholder="000-000-0000">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Nombres:</label>
                                <input name="nombreD" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Apellido Paterno:</label>
                                <input name="apelP" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Apellido Materno:</label>
                                <input name="apelM" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Lugar de Origen:</label>
                                <input name="lugarOrigen" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="main">Relación con la persona juridica tratante:</label>
                                <input name="relacion" type="text" placeholder="00000">
                                <span class="error"></span> </div>

                            <div class="field buttons">
                                <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
                                <button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Anterior</button>
                                <button id="enviar" name="enviar" onclick="almacenarArray()" class="submit">Enviar</button>

                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <span id="invalid"></span>
                </form>





            </div>
        </div>
```